# Запятую на стыке союзов нужно ставить?

Tags: запятые

Хотя, если разобраться, то выбирать Марусе было практически не из чего. Это из Довлатова, правда, на одном сайте, а не в бумажном варианте.
Здесь есть вторая часть союза если... то. По правилам тогда на стыке союзов запятая не должна быть.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно без запятой:Хотя если разобраться, то выбирать Марусе было практически не из чего.

Запятая не ставится, если структура предложения не может быть изменена путем перестановки придаточного предложения. В частности, такая перестановка невозможна при наличии двойных союзов:ЧЕМ...ТЕМ, ЕСЛИ...ТО, КОГДА...ТО, ХОТЯ...НО.

Пример: "Хотя если заглянуть в расписание моих поездок и выступлений только за 1996 год, то получается вроде бы не так уж и мало".

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с Софией. Обычно придаточную часть можно безболезненно "вынуть" из предложения. Если это сделать с нашим примером, получится:"Хотя то выбирать Марусе было практически не из чего"